# rtorrent: Move a completed download

Tags: bittorrent, rtorrent

After upgrading to rTorrent 0.9.8, my old rTorrent configuration-file did not work. By reading the docs, I used the new example and just adjusted the directories. However, I have one problem: After rTorrent has completed a download, I want to move the completed file/directory to another location (and still seed the file). I do not want anything fancy like labels, or moving based on type of download, just a simple 1:1 move from one dir to another.

I have defined two variables: `cfg.download` (a "InProgress"-dir and `cfg.complete` (a "Completed"-dir), and I have read both the [official documentation](https://rtorrent-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use-cases.html#versatile-move-on-completion), [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RTorrent#Manage_completed_files) and [rTrorrent's Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RTorrent#Manage_completed_files). I was sure the latter would work, but it gives me an `Invalid key`-error.

This is my attmept so far:

```
method.insert = cfg.complete, private|const|string, (cat,"/mypath/Completed/")

## Move files after download has finished
method.insert = d.get_finished_dir, simple, "(cat, (cfg.complete)),$d.custom1="
method.insert = d.data_path, simple, "if=(d.is_multi_file), (cat,(d.directory),/), (cat,(d.directory),/,(d.name))"
method.insert = d.move_to_complete, simple, "d.directory.set=$argument.1=; execute=mkdir,-p,$argument.1=; execute=mv,-u,$argument.0=,$argument.1=; d.save_full_session="
method.set_key = event.download.finished,move_complete,"d.move_to_complete=$d.data_path=,$d.get_finished_dir="
```

The error is:

```
rtorrent: Error in option file: ~/.rtorrent.rc:104: Invalid key.
```

where line 104 is `method.insert = d.data_path......`

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same error.

In my config `method.insert = d.data_path...` was already defined a few lines earlier, attempting to redefine it via the pasted config segment from the official documentation failed.

Removing the second (identical) definition of the d.data_path method fixed it for me.